# Find item from a list using nested find keyword in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have an enum class which will hold different states of the app.

```
enum class State {
    STATE_1, STATE_2, STATE_4, READY, UNKNOWN
}
```

I will have a list that contains these states in some random order. I want to write an algorithm that will return a particular state if other states are not available. For example:

```
val list = listOf(READY, STATE_2, STATE_1)
```

return `STATE_2`

```
val list = listOf(READY, STATE_1)
```

return `STATE_1`

```
val list = listOf(STATE_2, STATE_1)
```

return `STATE_2`

```
val list = listOf(UNKNOWN, STATE_2)
```

return `STATE_2`

I am searching for something that will help me do nested `find` over a collection in kotlin.

This is what I have achieved till now:

```
private fun filter(states: List<State>): State {
    val currentStates = states.filter {
        it != State.UNKNOWN || it != State.READY
    }

    currentStates.find { it == State.STATE_4 }?.let {
        return it
    } ?: currentStates.find { it == State.STATE_2 }?.let {
        return it
    } ?: currentStates.find { it == State.STATE_1 }?.let {
        return it
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define your enum states in order by what "wins" the filter:

```
enum class State {
    READY, UNKNOWN, STATE_1, STATE_2, STATE_4
}
```

Then you can pick the one with the highest ordinal:

```
fun filter(states: List<State>): State = 
    states.maxBy(State::ordinal) ?: error("Must have at least one state")
```

This assumes there is at least one State in the provided list. If that's not a safe assumption, you can return a nullable:

```
fun filter(states: List<State>): State? = states.maxBy(State::ordinal)
```

If there's some reason you can't rely on defining them in a certain order, you can provide the order as a list (or linked Set to make it fool-proof) in this function:

```
fun filter(states: List<State>): State {
    val order = linkedSetOf(State.READY, State.UNKNOWN, State.STATE_1, State.STATE_2, State.STATE_4)
    assert(order.size == State.values().size) // To ensure this function is updated if States are updated.
    return states.maxBy { order.indexOf(it) } ?: error("Must have at least one state")
}
```

Comment: I thought the same but there is a high chance other devs might not respect the order in the future.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I like it. Especially the assert part.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is much you can optimize. I can only think of using loop over predefined priorities like following

```kotlin
private val PRIORITY = listOf(State.STATE_4, State.STATE_2, State.STATE_1)

private fun filter(states: List<State>): State? {
    val currentStates = states.filter {
        it != State.UNKNOWN || it != State.READY
    }
    PRIORITY.forEach { prio ->
        currentStates.find { it == prio }?.let {
            return it
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

**Note**: I'm using nullable `State?` as return type instead of `State` for the cases when nothing appropriate is found within a collection.